# Python psycopg2 not able to connect to postgres server "psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host, no encryption"

Tags: python, postgresql, azure, psycopg2, azure-postgresql

I am trying to connect to a postgres database from my python script using the psycopg2 library. But I am getting the following error

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(host = <hostname>, port = 5432, database = <db_name>, user = <user_name>, password = <password>)
```

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "<MY IP ADDRESS>", user <user_name>, database <db_name>, no encryption
```

However, my IP address has already been added to the whitelist and I am able to connect to the database from the same computer using PgAdmin and VS Code. So it doesn't appear to be a case of IP whitelisting

Any idea why this might be happening ?

P.S: The postgres database is setup in Azure cloud

Comment: Are you connecting to the same database as the same user with the same password?

Comment: Yes. Connecting to the same database with same username and password.

Comment: Have you tried `sslmode=prefer` to set up an SSL connection?

Comment: 1) Define what you mean by `whitelist`. 2) The error is specific `...no pg_hba.conf entry...` so are you sure the host you are connecting from is set up in the file?

Comment: Was that the only error message you got, or was there perhaps an immediately prior error message you overlooked?

Comment: check if your system IP address  in within the range of  ip address you added ```import  psycopg2
src_conn_string = "SourceConnectionString"
dst_conn_string = "DStConnectionString"
try:
src_conn = psycopg2.connect(src_conn_string)
src_cursor = src_conn.cursor()
print("Connected to source database.")
try:
dst_conn = psycopg2.connect(dst_conn_string)
dst_cursor = dst_conn.cursor()
print("Connected to destination database.")```

Comment: you check the address with [ipconfig](https://i.imgur.com/G1XEiKc.png) and in networking Or you can remove the all ip address added and the application again

Comment: "IPv4 Address" under the network adapter you are connected to. The IP address listed there is your system's IP address. I have cross-checked it [Output](https://i.imgur.com/QbRU0Dv.png). hope it helps

Comment: For more details refer this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/single-server/connect-python)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- To add [Firewall rules](https://i.imgur.com/vZ43wzk.png).

[image]

[image]

- **Tried this code from this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/single-server/connect-python):**

```py
import  psycopg2
host = "sampath.postgres.database.azure.com"
dbname = "postgres"
user = "sampath"
password = "*sam"
sslmode = "require"  
src_conn_string = "host={0} user={1} dbname={2} password={3} sslmode={4}".format(host,  user,  dbname,  password,  sslmode)
try:
src_conn = psycopg2.connect(src_conn_string)
src_cursor = src_conn.cursor()
print("Connected to the source database.")
src_cursor.close()
src_conn.close()
print("Disconnected from the source database.")
except  psycopg2.Error  as  src_error:
print("Error connecting to the source database:",  src_error)
```

- To [Connect with Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/single-server/connect-python)  PostgreSQL with for without [Firewall rules](https://i.imgur.com/WKuzZEp.png) and make sure the delete the PostgreSQL Firewall rules(or) Existing server.

**Output with FireWall Rule:**

[image]