# RabbitMQ Shovel to Azure Event Hub or Service Bus

Tags: azure, rabbitmq, azure-eventhub, servicebus

I am hoping someone has got this to work.
I am the trying to connect RabbitMQ shovel to Azure Event hub or Service Bus.
I found two tutorials on MS, (very short to set up) but both results in the shovel error.
The request to Event hub or Service bus is success in the example.

My guess is that something is missing from the below tutorials or that some components have been changed and breaking changes has been introduced:

Importing Data from RabbitMQ into Azure Data Explorer via Event Hubs
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-explorer-blog/importing-data-from-rabbitmq-into-azure-data-explorer-via-event/ba-p/3777688
Shovel error

AMQP allows for interconnecting connecting brokers directly, for instance using routers like Apache Qpid Dispatch Router or broker-native "shovels" like the one of RabbitMQ.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-overview

How to integrate Service Bus with RabbitMQ
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-integrate-with-rabbitmq

Version:
RabbitMQ 3.10.7, Erlang 25.0

Case and steps:
Adding a new Azure Service Bus Namespace
rabbitmq01
basic
public endpoint
Creating our Azure Service Bus Queue
from-rabbitmq01

Enabling the RabbitMQ Shovel Plugin

`rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_shovel_management`

Created queue in Rabbitmq
telemetry01

Connecting RabbitMQ to Azure Service Bus
Add SAS Policy, Manage now, tested with just send also.
rabbitmq-shovel01
Primary Connection String

Connection String to AMQP
https://red-mushroom-0f7446a0f.azurestaticapps.net/
amqps://rabbitmq-shovel01:SAS-KEY@rabbitmq01.servicebus.windows.net:5671/?sasl=plain

TNC

`Test-NetConnection -ComputerName rabbitmq01.servicebus.windows.net -Port 5671 = True`

Make the dynamic shovel with above properties.
Shovel was done exactly like the tutorial
The shovel status is just starting, never goes to running.

Log:

`2023-07-08 19:09:56.385000+02:00 [error] <0.742.0>     supervisor: {<0.742.0>,amqp10_client_connection_sup} 2023-07-08 19:09:56.385000+02:00 [error] <0.742.0>     errorContext: start_error 2023-07-08 19:09:56.385000+02:00 [error] <0.742.0>     reason: {badmatch,{error,closed}}`
[...]
`2023-07-08 19:09:56.386000+02:00 [error] <0.744.0> ** Stacktrace = 2023-07-08 19:09:56.386000+02:00 [error] <0.744.0> **  [{amqp10_client_frame_reader,init,1, 2023-07-08 19:09:56.386000+02:00 [error] <0.744.0>                                  [{file,"amqp10_client_frame_reader.erl"}, 2023-07-08 19:09:56.386000+02:00 [error] <0.744.0>                                   {line,109}]}, 2023-07-08 19:09:56.386000+02:00 [error] <0.744.0>      {gen_statem,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_statem.erl"},{line,1001}]}, 2023-07-08 19:09:56.386000+02:00 [error] <0.744.0>      {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,240}]}]`
[...]
`2023-07-08 19:09:56.386000+02:00 [error] <0.688.0> Shovel 'rmq-2-sb' could not connect to destination 2023-07-08 19:09:56.387000+02:00 [error] <0.687.0>     supervisor: {<0.687.0>,rabbit_shovel_dyn_worker_sup}`

[Shovel to Bus requests success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2xe4.jpg)

Tested

1. I have tried to change TLS version in Service bus.
2. Enabled rabbitmq_amqp1_0 plugin, https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-amqp1.0.
3. Tested a lot of combinations with the URI. After testing https://red-mushroom-0f7446a0f.azurestaticapps.net/ and URL enconding.
4. Azure ServiceBus can be used with the AMQP 1.0 protocol. Since version 3.7 RabbitMQ supports shovels where either the source or destination (or both) uses AMQP 1.0. https://gist.github.com/kjnilsson/159c643fb34604f8ea20be336109261b

I have sent a mail to RabbitMQ community also.
Thank you in advance

11.07.2023 Update
New RabbitMQ 3.12.1 and Erlang 26.0

Today I did a new test with both tutorials. For the Event hub i followed it exactly. The shovel error is:
`2023-07-11 10:01:57.638000+02:00 [error] <0.2006.0>     supervisor: {<0.2006.0>,amqp10_client_connection_sup}`
`2023-07-11 10:01:57.638000+02:00 [error] <0.2006.0>     errorContext: start_error`
`2023-07-11 10:01:57.638000+02:00 [error] <0.2006.0>     reason: {options,incompatible,[{verify,verify_peer},{cacerts,undefined}]}`
[...]
`2023-07-11 10:09:27.788000+02:00 [error] <0.2476.0> Shovel 'shovel-07' could not connect to destination`

For the Service bus it is the same.

First I tried with shovel Source AMQP 0.9.1, Destination, AMQP 1.0.
:
`2023-07-11 10:44:41.042000+02:00 [error] <0.3627.0>     supervisor: {<0.3627.0>,amqp10_client_connection_sup}`
`2023-07-11 10:44:41.042000+02:00 [error] <0.3627.0>     errorContext: start_error`
`2023-07-11 10:44:41.042000+02:00 [error] <0.3627.0>     reason: {options,incompatible,[{verify,verify_peer},{cacerts,undefined}]}`
[...]
`2023-07-11 10:44:41.043000+02:00 [error] <0.3610.0> Shovel 'shovel_01' could not connect to destination`

Then I tried shovel Source AMQP 1.0, Destination, AMQP 1.0.

And as expected:
`2023-07-11 11:08:18.155000+02:00 [error] <0.8999.0> amqp1_0_plugin_not_enabled`

Enabled plugin amqp1_0

`2023-07-11 11:14:58.438000+02:00 [error] <0.9613.0>     supervisor: {<0.9613.0>,amqp10_client_connection_sup}`
`2023-07-11 11:14:58.438000+02:00 [error] <0.9613.0>     errorContext: start_error`
`2023-07-11 11:14:58.438000+02:00 [error] <0.9613.0>     reason: {options,incompatible,[{verify,verify_peer},{cacerts,undefined}]}`
[...]
`2023-07-11 11:14:58.438000+02:00 [error] <0.9582.0> Shovel 'shovel_03' could not connect to destination`

After update to: RabbitMQ 3.12.1 and Erlang 26.0
.So it has do to with TLS, and that was not a step in any of the tutorials.
This is gonna take time :) Any help is appreciated

I got in touch with MS, as per delivered test results, they did not find a issue with the test(s) done. TNC images validated connectivity. Further troubleshooting will be done by support. Looking forward to that. Collaboration is key.

Comment: Make sure you navigate to the service bus queue, create a [policy](https://i.imgur.com/ponRJq4.png), and [convert it](https://i.imgur.com/yFD200q.png)

Comment: from the [reference](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-explorer-blog/importing-data-from-rabbitmq-into-azure-data-explorer-via-event/ba-p/3777688) able to connect to [rabbitmqqtt](https://i.imgur.com/iXfHUWn.png)                   [queue](https://i.imgur.com/DBoFirA.png) and [messages](https://i.imgur.com/t4VvWCJ.png)

Comment: go to Admin -> Shovel Management, where you can add your new shovel that will take care of sending messages from a RabbitMQ queue to your Azure Service Bus queue as per the [MSDOC](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-explorer-blog/importing-data-from-rabbitmq-into-azure-data-explorer-via-event/ba-p/3777688)

Comment: Hi Sampath and thanks for helping.  I have no issue with making the shovel, that is ok :) The image "policy" you uploaded is from the Azure Service bus policy, but the tutorial your are "referencing" in your comment is for Azure Event Hub. But policy is policy :) I have done Importing Data from RabbitMQ into Azure Data Explorer via Event Hubs tutorial now. Were am I wrong per the tutorial? I have done 3 mores test now. Same result every time Here is the result https://github.com/spawnmarvel/test/blob/main/RabbitMQ%202%20Azure%20Event%20Hub.pdf

Comment: Hi Sampath, Done with How to integrate Service Bus with RabbitMQ. Result: https://github.com/spawnmarvel/test/blob/main/RabbitMQ%202%20Azure%20Service%20Bus.pdf Result is the same for me in both tutorials. Shovel x could not start: - 2023-07-12[error] <0.5449.0> exception exit: {options,incompatible, 2023-07-12 [error] <0.5449.0> [{verify,verify_peer},{cacerts,undefined}]} - So this must be due to TLS and the URI. Tls is not mentioned as a step. Azure Service Bus->Networking, minimum tls 1.2, Local Authentication ->Enabled. (default properties) implemented. What have you configured?

Comment: Hi Sampath, can you also show me a picture of the Shovel Status, where is says "running" on your setup? (Name-State-Source-Destination-Last changed) I hope you have time to view the 2 pdf's with the implementation and results. The tutorial is are very short. Thank you

Comment: for TLS is network related error Refer to This for  [Ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76583406/python-psycopg2-not-able-to-connect-to-postgres-server-psycopg2-operationalerro/76593045#76593045)

Comment: Ok, will give to a sample of how to connect with the Azure service bus with RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.erlang.org/blog/otp-26-highlights/
Erlang/OTP 26 Highlights
May 16, 2023
[...]
Erlang/OTP 26 Highlights
In OTP 26, the default value for the verify option is now verify_peer instead of verify_none.
Host verification requires trusted CA certificates to be supplied using one of the options cacerts or cacertsfile.
Therefore, a connection attempt with an empty option list will fail in OTP 26:

```
{error,{options,incompatible,
                [{verify,verify_peer},{cacerts,undefined}]}}
```

The default value for the cacerts option is undefined, which is not compatible with the {verify,verify_peer} option.
To make the connection succeed, the recommended way is to use the cacerts option to supply CA certificates to be used for verifying.

This is the breaking change (I would believe) after 16.05.2023:

```
amqps://rabbitmq-shovel:StringOfRandomChars@rabbitmq.servicebus.windows.net:5671/?sasl=plain
```

Is must be on format similar to this I would belive:

```
amqps://rabbitmq-shovel:StringOfRandomChars@rabbitmq.servicebus.windows.net:5671/?cacertfile=/path/to/cacert_root_certificate_servicebus.pem&verify=verify_peer (something??)
```

So https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-integrate-with-rabbitmq must be updated with new information and the tool https://red-mushroom-0f7446a0f.azurestaticapps.net/ must also generate new URI with ssl stuff, and I would belive the public root certificate for Azure Service Bus must be obtainable. Input in this?

15.07.2023 update
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-explorer-blog/importing-data-from-rabbitmq-into-azure-data-explorer-via-event/ba-p/3777688
Tutorial version: RabbitMQ 3.11.7 Erlang 25.2.

Tested with RabbitMQ 3.11.10 Erlang 25.2.

RabbitMQ log:

```
2023-07-15 10:38:00.787000+02:00 [warning] <0.1427.0> Description: "Server authenticity is not verified since certificate path validation is not enabled"
2023-07-15 10:38:00.787000+02:00 [warning] <0.1427.0>      Reason: "The option {verify, verify_peer} and one of the options 'cacertfile' or 'cacerts' are required to enable this."
2023-07-15 10:38:00.787000+02:00 [warning] <0.1427.0> 
2023-07-15 10:38:01.394000+02:00 [error] <0.1408.0> Shovel 'rmq2eh' in virtual host '/' is stopping, reason: {outbound_link_detached,
2023-07-15 10:38:01.394000+02:00 [error] <0.1408.0>                                                           {'v1_0.error',
2023-07-15 10:38:01.394000+02:00 [error] <0.1408.0>                                                            {symbol,
2023-07-15 10:38:01.394000+02:00 [error] <0.1408.0>                                                             <<"amqp:unauthorized-access">>},

 [...] 2023-07-15 10:49:09.143000+02:00 hostname =>
2023-07-15 10:49:09.143000+02:00 <<"xxxxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net">>,
```

The tutorial(s) must be update with highest RabbitMQ and Erlang version it supports, so that new user know what version(s) they can use and what are the dependency's.. I will do one test with same RabbitMQ version used in the hub tutorial if I can find it. The Erlang version used for this test is the same.

Update versions (could not find 3.11.7):
RabbitMQ 3.11.0 Erlang 25.2 result:

```
2023-07-15 11:46:16.886000+02:00 [error] <0.2202.0> Shovel 'rmq2ev114' in virtual host '/' is stopping, reason: {outbound_link_detached,
2023-07-15 11:46:16.886000+02:00 [error] <0.2202.0>                                                              {'v1_0.error',
2023-07-15 11:46:16.886000+02:00 [error] <0.2202.0>                                                               {symbol,
2023-07-15 11:46:16.886000+02:00 [error] <0.2202.0>                                                                <<"amqp:unauthorized-access">>},
[...]
2023-07-15 11:46:16.887000+02:00 [warning] <0.2220.0>                                                                                    hostname =>
2023-07-15 11:46:16.887000+02:00 [warning] <0.2220.0>                                                                                     <<"xxxxx.servicebus.windows.net">>,
[...]
2023-07-15 11:46:21.895000+02:00 [warning] <0.2254.0> Description: "Server authenticity is not verified since certificate path validation is not enabled"
2023-07-15 11:46:21.895000+02:00 [warning] <0.2254.0>      Reason: "The option {verify, verify_peer} and one of the options 'cacertfile' or 'cacerts' are required to enable this."
```

15.07.2023 18:11 It works now finally.
It now works for Azure Event Hub and for Azure Service bus, new URI with TLS and Azure Root certificate and had to add an extra root policy also to the namespace for each service, not just the sub SAS
https://github.com/spawnmarvel/test/blob/main/it_works.jpg

I am out, I am done, my life is back.

Comment: Downloaded cert DigiCert Global Root CA from  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/azure-ca-details?tabs=root-and-subordinate-cas-list. used uri. `amqps://policy14:SAS-TOKEN@xxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net?cacertfile=c:/RabbitMQBaseFolder/cert//DigiCertGlobalRootCA.pem&verify=verify_none`.Result: `2023-07-15 12:56:54.291000+02:00 [error] <0.18351.0>` result: `<<"amqp:unauthorized-access">>},` No TLS error just unauthorized-access

Comment: Installed RabbitMQ 3.12.1 Erlang 26.0 and moved from policy send to using new policy: Add SAS Policy (Manage) name: policymanage
URI:amqps://policymanage:SAS-TOKEN@XXXXXX.servicebus.windows.net?cacertfile=c:/RabbitMQBaseFolder/cert/DigiCertGlobalRootCA.pem&verify=verify_none
Result:`2023-07-15 14:06:44.420000+02:00 [error] <0.4342.0> Shovel 'test_04' in virtual host '/' is stopping, reason: {outbound_link_detached, [..]                                                         <<"amqp:unauthorized-access">>},` view https://github.com/spawnmarvel/test/blob/main/unauthorized-access.jpg

Comment: It now works for Azure Event Hub and for Azure Service bus, new URI with TLS and Azure Root certificate and had to add an extra root policy also to the namespace for each service, not just the sub SAS. https://github.com/spawnmarvel/test/blob/main/it_works.jpg

Answer (score 0):

**Sample RabbitMQ Shovel to Azure Service Bus:**

- Enable the required

`rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_shovel_management`
`rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_shovel`

`rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`

- using this [RabbitMQ with Service Bus](https://dev.to/azure/how-to-bridge-rabbitmq-with-azure-service-bus-98l#:%7E:text=How%20to%20bridge%20RabbitMQ%20with%20Service%20Bus%201,Azure%20Service%20Bus%20...%206%20Let%27s%20Recap%20)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

- Refer This for  [Ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76583406/python-psycopg2-not-able-to-connect-to-postgres-server-psycopg2-operationalerro/76593045#76593045) and for [servicebus](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/rabbitmq-service-bus/)

[image]

[image]

- For details Refer to this Creating [Importing Data from RabbitMQ into Azure Data Explorer via Event Hubs tutorial](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-explorer-blog/importing-data-from-rabbitmq-into-azure-data-explorer-via-event/ba-p/3777688).

Comment: Hi Sampath and thank you very much for all help.
I have read it all and understand it. 
You say" for TLS is network related error Refer to This for 'ip address'", -> AD PostgreSQL ->Networking?
The only issue I have is connecting the shovel using the URI to the Azure Service Bus.
"By default, Service Bus namespaces are accessible from the internet as long as the request contains valid authentication and authorization. "
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-ip-filtering
TNC -ComputerName xxxxx.servicebus.windows.net -Port 5671, TcpTestSucceeded: True.

Comment: So in all of my tests, this is always true: TNC -ComputerName xxxxx.servicebus.windows.net -Port 5671, TcpTestSucceeded: True. But when adding the converted URI from ASB URI to AMQP URI and press add the shovel. The status is always, "Starting" and the log is always: shovel x could not start, {options,incompatible,[{verify,verify_peer},{cacerts,undefined}

Comment: @sampath I thank you for all the effort and help. I will continue my journey with this. For  me it did not work. Still an unclear issue with authentication and authorization in both tutorials.

Comment: The error facing is related to a system configuration issue. Please cross [check](https://i.imgur.com/wLQgyJ1.png) your enviroment .Thank you.

Comment: @sampath, again thank you. I will try to find the solution. From all the available pdf 's on Github and comments here: TNC -ComputerName xxxxx.servicebus.windows.net -Port 5671, TcpTestSucceeded: True always with Public access in Azure.
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName (Specifies the Domain Name System (DNS) name or IP address of the target computer.) -Port (Specifies the TCP port number on the remote computer. The cmdlet uses this port number to test connectivity to the remote computer.), TcpTestSucceeded: True indicates that the connection was successful and the port is open.

Comment: one strange thing here: Your RabbitMQ shovel "add shovel" image uses Endpoint=sb:, but your Dynamic shovel has amqps://. You can view it above or here
https://github.com/spawnmarvel/test/blob/main/difference.jpg: Is that the correct? The docs said otherwise....

Comment: yes with amqps://. uploaded the right image sorry 3 and 4 image it is correct .

Comment: good that you found solution with Installed RabbitMQ 3.12.1 Erlang 26.0 and moved from policy send to using new policy.

Comment: could you check my answer and vote on it. I have added link to images showing result. Thank you (I am not allowed to vote..)

Answer (score 0):

I got in touch with MS, as per delivered test results, they did not find a issue with the test(s) done. TNC images validated connectivity. Further troubleshooting will be done by support. Looking forward to that. Collaboration is key.

Comment: assistance not needed, but talked over some mails. Solved it myself.