# unable to connect local node.js with CosmosDb having public access and private link enabled

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-private-link

i have a node.js application running from my local mac. I use it connect to AzureCosmos db instances which have public access enabled without error.

I created a cosmosdb instance with private-endpoint and public access enabled.

In my node.js application i use the endpoint which is public(i.e without private endpoint enabled)

the privatelink format is

```
testcosmosdb.privatelink.mongo.cosmos.azure.com
```

In my node.js application i use the endpoint which is public(i.e without private endpoint in the string, `testcosmosdb.mongo.cosmos.azure.com`)

```
MONGODB_CONNECTION="mongodb://testcosmosdb:xR7xqQPOeMegN2LuXPVt5IUwb9HsGEyC0mkASzNwlmb6PEwehRkZCNpfrCxHHErqyP7lCXjxjWwACDbftND3w==@testcosmosdb.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb&retrywrites=false&maxIdleTimeMS=120000&appName=@testcosmosdb@"
```

getting this error when the app tries to retrieve collection from cosmosdb:

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 20.63.92.0:10255 closed
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/my-dev/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:277:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'testcosmosdb.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'globaldb',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
} [
  'MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 20.63.92.0:10255 closed',
  '    at Timeout._onTimeout (/my-dev/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:277:38)',
  '    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)',
  '    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)'
]
```

I am not getting this error for cosmosdb instances with just public access and no private endpoints.

if i do ns lookup i am getting proper response

```
nslookup testcosmosdb.mongo.cosmos.azure.com

Server: 3201:1200:61a9:6b1c::ee

Address: 2301:3900:71c9:5f1c::8e#53

Non-authoritative answer:

testcosmosdb.mongo.cosmos.azure.com canonical name = testcosmosdb.privatelink.mongo.cosmos.azure.com.

testcosmosdb.privatelink.mongo.cosmos.azure.com canonical name = ces-ms-prod-westeurope1-fe1.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com.

Name: ces-ms-prod-westeurope1-fe1.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com

Address: 20.63.92.0
```

Can anyone help here? Thanks

Comment: please check your system IP address and in the networking tab refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76583406/python-psycopg2-not-able-to-connect-to-postgres-server-psycopg2-operationalerro/76593045#76593045)

Comment: with code i was able to```connect const mongoose = require('mongoose'); const username = ''; const password = ''; const hostname = ''; const port = 10255;  const dbName = ''; const mongoURI = ``;   const Schema = mongoose.Schema; const userSchema = new Schema({   name: String,   email: String, }); mongoose.connect(mongoURI, {   useNewUrlParser: true,   useUnifiedTopology: true, }).then(() => {   console.log('Connected to Azure Cosmos DB'); }).catch((err) => {   console.error('Error connecting to Azure Cosmos DB:', err); });```